# How can I login multiple username and paasword using csv data set config in jmeter3.0?

Tags: java, jmeter

**In http request, I have set the variable names are**

```
username=$(name)          
password=$(psw)
```

**In CSV data set config set the details are:**

```
File name: /home/desktop/login.txt            
Variable name: name,psw             
Delimiter use: ,
```

**In CSV file, I have three user accounts are:**

```
radha,radha            
sumithra,sumithra        
moorthi,moorthi
```

In the above configuration, I have run the `jmeter3.0` in Linux . But, It does not read the `CSV/txt file` data. the below invalid request passing my application.

**POST data:**

```
username=%24%28name%29&password=%24%28psw%29&userstate=others&submit=Enter
```

Kindly give me a useful solution.

Comment: [Reference](http://www.roman10.net/2012/07/28/apache-jmeter-input-from-file-with-http-testing-as-an-example/). Let us know if you need any more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every step you have followed seems okay here. But as I can see you have missed declaring the variable properly in your scripts. In your Http request sampler, you have to send parameter as like below:

```
username=${name}
password=${psw}
```

**In Http sampler:**

[image]

> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

So in your case, POST data is shown as **"username=%24%28name%29"** because of the `(` and `)`.

For Reference, See [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: Just use `{}` instead of `()` in your parameter value in this case. I've already given my answer. What problems are you facing right now?